# Possible to show a "in App Store modal" in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, ios6

Is it possible to show a modal view controller in iOS 6 that present my app in App Store?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Yes you can. (iOS6+)**

Take a look at [SKStoreProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html)

```
NSDictionary *appParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"533886215"
                                                          forKey:SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier];

SKStoreProductViewController *productViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
[productViewController setDelegate:self];
[productViewController loadProductWithParameters:appParameters
                                 completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error)
{

}];
[self presentViewController:productViewController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^{

                 }];
```

Comment: Just a note that the first line can also be written as

NSDictionary *appParameters = @{
    SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: @"533886215"
};

for better readability.

Comment: The call to present the product view controller should be done inside the completion block of `loadProductWithParameters` (assuming a positive result). And the call to `loadProductWithParameters` should be done on a background thread.

Comment: Just a note that you have to import StoreKit framework, and it doesn't work in the simulator.

Comment: @maddy the completion block of loadProductWithParameters won't fitre at all until you try to present the product view controller.

Comment: From link: "Sorry, that page cannot be found."